# Unable to start mongodb using supervisor file

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, supervisord

I've got a docker container, in which I'm installing mongo db. After installing, 
I'm trying to start mongo and restore a mongo db dump. However, when I start the docker instance, I see that the user has been switched to root (as per supervisor instruction) but mongo is not started.

This is the supervisor snippet:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:mongodb]
user=root
command=/usr/bin/mongod
```

This is my setup in the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf

# Install MongoDB.
RUN \
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10  && \ 
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' 
| tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y mongodb-org && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/data/db"]

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define default command.
CMD ["mongod"]

EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 28017

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Am I missing any configuration setting? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you use the [official MongoDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/) image or is this more of a learning exercise?

Comment: Do you have the logs from the container?

Comment: I tested your Dockerfile using FROM ubuntu:latest and the database was started and accepted connections. Of course, you do not need the first CMD as it will be overwritten by the second one. It would be nice if you could provide some logs.

Comment: Hi. I'm not using the official MongoDB. I'm installing other software, that for my particular use case needs to be in the same container. For the moment swarming different containers is out of the question. I'll post the logs shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to run mongodb because while installing mongodb some files need authentication, so you just have to replace `apt-get install -y mongodb-org` with `apt-get install -y --no-authentication mongodb-org` and you'll be able to install mongodb without any problem.